Pure sine wave function with tunnable valley peak ratio
I couldn't find any on internet for sine-wave similar like PWM in square wave. Where I can tune the sine-wave valley-peak ratio. Where 100% ratio means 100% peak (or 0% valley), the graphic will simply straight line at y=1. 0% ratio means 0% peak (or 100% valley), the graphic will simply straight line at y=-1. While the ratio 50% is just a regular sine wave.
I expect there is a sine function that accepts Pulse-Width param ratio like that, but for sine wave.

One simple way would be to do linear interpolation. Assuming you have a ratio $r$ that goes from 0 to 1 you could define a function as
$$y_r(t) = 2r-1 + (1-2|r-0.5|)\sin(\omega t) $$
which would give you something like this (which may or may not be what you want). Note that PWM works differently: it adjusts the duty cycle of the square wave. But that concept doesn't really translate to a regular sine wave.

EDIT based on comment

I would expect PWM like, which it's manipulating the horizontal ratio instead of vertical ratio

That's difficult to do for a sine wave and I have a hard time visualizing that. You could potentially warp the time axis of half a period and flip and repeat. That would look something like this but I have no idea if that fits your needs or not.


I would expect PWM like, which it's manipulating the horizontal ratio instead of vertical ratio.

See edit for an alternative. I have a hard time visualizing this for a sine wave.

that's better, perhaps I can tune with interference between 50% PWM and 10%PWM with the another phase shifting version.
